# Black Screen on Boot & Resume From Sleep with DisplayPort

Tags: boot, drivers, motherboard, troubleshooting, displayport

I am having an issue on a new system build where occasionally on boot and resuming from sleep I get a black screen. I've read thousands (ok...maybe hundreds) of posts and articles regarding similar issues but nothing that totally matches up or has a solution.

This is a new system build with an Asus Z390 Prime A, i7 9700k, Nvidia Quadro M2000 graphics card. When I reboot, restart or shut down and start up I randomly get a black screen. About 1 out of every 4 or 5 start ups.

Steps I've taken so far:

1. All latest drivers, bios and windows updates installed
2. Tested memory several times - all pass
3. Ran CPU stress tests on Cinebench - stable
4. Intel processor diagnostic utility - pass
5. Integrated and discrete GPU stress test with LuxMark
6. Reinstalled Windows 3 times

When this happened on my first install, I looked through event log and found some random warning and errors that were representative of windows corruption so I repaired windows with SFC and dism with the windows base image. That didn't help, and so I reinstalled windows.

On the next install I noticed the same issue, so I was thinking it might be a hardware problem. Ran all stress tests, memory check, hard drive surface scans. Made sure the psu was delivering the correct voltage. Then I went down the driver rabbit hole and found that the AI Suite drivers "could" have been the issue by running windows driver verifier. I found the drivers that came with Asus' utilities were giving me the most faults and so I reinstalled this time not installing any of Asus' utility software. I believe the Asus drivers were causing the windows corruption because on the new install I did not have that issue but the black screen still persists.

When the issue continued on the latest install, I removed the Quadro card and plugged the display port adapter into the integrated graphics and the issue happened again. I read several other posts about display port and adapters causing boot issues so I used HDMI on the integrated port and haven't had an issue since.

Could the issue be the display port adapters being used? I have a few that claim to be 4k v1.2, which I thought would sufficient. Swapping them out does not seem to work.

Could it also be a faulty chipset on the motherboard? Maybe that's what causes the corruption in Windows. How can I test for that?

Any ideas on how I could troubleshoot further or should I just exchange the MB and start over?

Comment: It could be a monitor or cable issue.

Comment: It seems to be happening when the computer goes to sleep and something brings it out of sleep but the system doesn't fully start. Is there anything I could do? Anyone think I should replace MoBo or Graphics Card?